# implement enum as immutable class in modern javascript (es2015)

Tags: javascript, enums, ecmascript-6

I need some help. I want to implement Enum with modern javascript. I want it to be immutable and think it will looks something like that:

```
class AlphabetEnum{
  static get A(){
     return 'a';
  },
  static get B(){
     return 'b';
  }
 ...
}
```

However, it's a bit annoying to write all this getters. So I'm curious - is there a chance to optimize this with compute method names and maybe some other es2015 features.

In result I dream to have something like that:

```
let alph = [a, b, c, ..., z];
class AlphabetEnum{
      static get [some__clever_way_to_resolve_names_from_<alph>](){
         return some_clever_way_to_understand_what's_called();
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A class makes just no sense. You don't a want a function with static getters. You just want an immutable object - and that's easy:

```
const AlphabetEnum = Object.freeze({
    A: "a",
    B: "b",
    …
});
```

Of course you can also dynamically create that if listing all properties is too cumbersome:

```
const AlphabetEnum = {};
for (let i=0; i<26; i++)
    AlphabetEnum[String.fromCharCode(65+i)] = String.fromCharCode(97+i);
Object.freeze(AlphabetEnum);
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd do it the same way is in ES5, with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
class AlphabetEnum {}

['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z'].forEach(letter => {
  Object.defineProperty(AlphabetEnum, letter.toUpperCase(), {
    get: () => letter,
    configurable: true, // remove this line if not needed / wanted
  });
});
```

However, using a `class` just for static properties is an anti-pattern IMO. In that case you can as well use a plain object:

```
var AlphabetEnum = {};
```

Comment: You may want to remove the comma after `configurable: true`, otherwise nice answer :).

Comment: @Arg0n: Why should I do that?

Comment: Because that's prettier! (Which is totally a fact, not an opinion) `v++`

Comment: @FelixKling Hmm, i just think it looks like an `object` and that you will get syntax error with the comma after the last property? But since you say you don't need to i guess you're right.

Comment: @Arg0n: A trailing comma in an object literal is not a syntax error :)

Comment: Doesn't ES2015/6 allow for hanging commas without warnings? Pretty sure I read that recently.

Comment: @FelixKling Well then i learned something new today. Even tho i think i'll stick to not using it :).

Comment: @Andy Only in *function* declarations/executions. `function f(a, b, c,)` used to be a syntax error, but perhaps not any longer ([Stage3 proposal for ES2016](https://jeffmo.github.io/es-trailing-function-commas/)). In Object (and Array) literals, this syntax is fine unless you're using some outdated IE version